# How can I configure e monitor a software process in Zabbix?

Tags: zabbix

I'm using Protheus ERP software and I would like to monitoring of the process is running by his port (not if the server is online but if the ERP is running). There is a possibility to make this?
Or in the case this is not possibly, there is another method to make?